# CSS :hover to affect 2 elements

Tags: css

So I have some CSS generating this.

[image: CSS Menu]

The HTML code as follows.

```
<div class="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                <div class="menutab"></div>
                <li><a href='about_us.html'>About Us</a></li>
                <div class="menutab"></div>
                <li><a href='#'>Order Online</a></li>
                <div class="menutab"></div>
                <li><a href='gallery.html'>Gallery</a></li>
                <div class="menutab"></div>
                <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
                <div class="menutab"></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu li{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: #EBE5D9;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.menu li:hover {
    background: #AEC32A;
}


.menu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: fantasy;
}



.menutab {
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -3px;
    margin-left: -71px;
    border-right: 21px solid #EBE5D9;
    border-bottom: 21px solid transparent;
}
```

Basically what I am wanting is for the hover effect to turn the whole thing green, currently .menu li:hover turns the block the colour #AEC32A but I also want it to turn the .menutab border the same colour, anyway of doing this? preferably without using Javascript.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no problem with the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).

Simply add this to your css:

```
.menu li:hover + .menutab{
    border-right-color: #AEC32A;
}
```

This selects the immediately preceeding element (`.menutab`) of the first element (`.menu li:hover`).

see the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hV6LA/)

[Browser-support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/#link2) is 100% if you don't care for old IEs <(=) 8;)

Answer (score 5):

Try the adjacent selector.

```
.menu li:hover+.menutab {
    border-right-color: #AEC32A;
}
```

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/udunax/1/edit)

Comment: This. Supported in IE8 onwards too.

Comment: @cosmicsafari it's supported in IE7 too with some bugs.